# getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAs' of undefined , in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i am trying to write a script to send mail and a pdf as attachment using app script but i keep getting this error

```html
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I1').getValue(); // getting number of rows by fetching value from a count function in sheet
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var link = row[1];// Fetching ID by using mid fuction in sheet
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(link);
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    var htmlBody = DriveApp.getFileById("14KhceDa2lg7ojnwzFwpfiJCCx-xldPPj")
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, {htmlBody: htmlBody}, {attachments: [file[0].getAs(MimeType.PDF)]})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get only file object using `DriveApp.getFileById` so use `file.getAs()` directly as shown in below code

```html
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('I1').getValue(); // getting number of rows by fetching value from a count function in sheet
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var link = row[1];// Fetching ID by using mid fuction in sheet
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(link);
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    var htmlBody = DriveApp.getFileById("14KhceDa2lg7ojnwzFwpfiJCCx-xldPPj")
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, {htmlBody: htmlBody}, {attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,'',{htmlBody: htmlBody,attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]})
```